# How do I change size of app icons in Activity Overview of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, gnome-42

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish development branch). As soon as I installed, I noticed that the icons present in "Show Applications" are smaller than expected (i.e. smaller than that used to be in other versions). So here it is:
[image: Icon Image]

As you can see here, the icons are too small and, yes, its too hard to read its name because some apps name comes in like five lines. Is there a way I can increase their size? Or do I have to stick like this?

Comment: I don't know if this is still up to date: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049325/how-do-i-resize-app-icons-in-applications-overview-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Nope @mashuptwice i already tried it.... didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem of the display resolution of your laptop*. I also have the exact issue with 22.04. I assume that you might have a resolution of **1336 x 786** or similar (lower than *1080p*). I feel that you and I are stuck in this from of app display in ubuntu until the next patch for this exact issue or a new release but, this is LTS so a very long wait.

---

*I assumed it's a laptop as I saw a battery icon in your screenshot